# Basic mvc and php insert issue

Tags: php

I am trying to do a basic insert to my book table, this is the code I have so far alsong with the error I am presented with.

**Model** (models > adminarea_model.php)

*adminarea_model.php*

```
public function create($title_text)
    {
        $title_text = strip_tags($title_text);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES (:title)";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':title' => $title_text));


        $count =  $query->rowCount();
        if ($count == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["feedback_negative"][] = FEEDBACK_NOTE_CREATION_FAILED;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**View** (views > admin > addBook.php)

*addBook.php*

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo URL;?>admin/create">
<label>Text of new note: </label><input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="submit" value='Create this note' autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

**Controller** (controllers > admin.php)

*admin.php*

```
public function create()
    {


        if (isset($_POST['title']) AND !empty($_POST['title'])) {
            $book_model = $this->loadModel('Admin');
            $book_model->create($_POST['title']);
        }
        header('location: ' . URL . 'admin/addBook');
    }
```

When I am on `admin/addBook` and I try to submit the form I receive the following error;

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\logintest\application\controllers\admin.php on line 43
```

Line 43 contains the following

```
$book_model->create($_POST['title']);
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Quite new to php/mvc here so any advice is welcome.

Comment: $book_model is not an object, you need to check loadModel function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is generated when you are trying to call a member function of a class and object is not referencing to that class, you didnot tell which mvc framework you are using but what i think this might be the fix of your error as in most of the frameworks they make object as follow:

```html
$book_model = $this->loadModel('adminarea');
```

Fix the line in your controller

Comment: Excellent! Now working thank you for explaining where I was going wrong :)